# how to convert Nested Object to an Nested array for react native tablee

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, error-handling, fetch-api

In this case, I'm having a nested object in my API, so I want to fetch data from Api and display in react native table. As react native table isn't display objects value, so I need to convert those object to an array and display in table.

anyone can help me to convert and map to array for display in table?

```
  const X= Object.values(data.data.items.fields);



  X.map((rowData, index) => (
                  <Row
                    key={index}
                    data={rowData}
                    ))
                />
```

Comment: Hi there Akash, I'd recommend playing around with Object.values, Object.keys and Object.entries a bit. If you hit a wall somewhere, then I'd be happy to help.

Comment: yeah i already go through with Object.values, Object.keys and Object.entries. What you are trying to saying if more clearly say, i'd appreciate that @dev404

Comment: @AkashGhosh whats the package youre using?

Answer (score -1):

You can convert your object to an array like that

```
let newArray = Object.keys(data.data.items.fields).map(item => data.data.items.fields[item]);

console.log('newArray', newArray);
```